# How can I / is there a way that I can make the star behave just like the sprinkles?

Tags: particles

I'm new to Blender and am following Blender Guru's donut tutorial. Unlike his donut (which had the sprinkles and a sphere) I decided to add a star because I thought it would look better. However the star didn't stay flat with the icing. What can I do to make it look right?[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go back to the part of the tutorial where he talks about making the sprinkles stay flat and apply it to the star.  The trick is that you need to orient the star the right way *in edit mode* so that the part you want to be flat against the donut is.

You just need to rotate the star 90 degrees on one axis to do that.

Comment: I forgot he did that. It works now. Thanks Marty!